# Exclude directories from list of files in ArrayList?

Tags: android, arraylist

I am using an ArrayList to store a list of files in a folder, for use as an adapter for a ListView. I want to exclude subfolders from the list however, but don't know how to do it. Can anyone advise?

My existing code is:

```
File f = new File(sourcePath);
ArrayList<String> elements = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(f.list()));
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
my_custom_adapter adapter = new my_custom_adapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, elements);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: just loop though the list from your f.list() method and exclude the one's that do not fail the isDirectory() method.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this. Do you mean loop through the ArrayList? I couldn't use the isDirectory method on a String ArrayList item.

Comment: Sorry for being slow, but what would the code be to loop through f.list and remove selected items?

Comment: f.list() return a list of strings but listFiles() return a list of File object, my other statement is wrong, see example posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a sample of how you can populate your arraylist elements with file names only,

```
ArrayList elements = new ArrayList();
File[] fls = f.listFiles(sourcePath);
for(int i=0; i<fls.length; i++)
{
  if(fls[i].isDirectory() == false)
    elements.add(fls[i].getPath());
}
```

Comment: This code gives an error on sourcePath on line 2 - "Cannot resolve method listFiles(java.lang.String)" ???

Comment: It's OK .listFiles() works. Thanks for all your help

Comment: exclude the file if the same name of a folder, right ?